# How do I calculate color gradient for 4 points?

Tags: c, image-processing, linear-gradients

Given the size of image and the pixel `value(r, g, b)` of four corners `A`,`B`,`C`,`D` (counterclockwise), I would like to generate the image by calculating the gradient between those point like this picture:

[image]

**My idea:**

For point `X`, I use linear interpolation to to calculate the rgb value respectively,  so `X = A + ((D-A)/|D-A|)*(|X-A|)`, however, this seems to ignore the dependence of other diagonal points(`B` and `D`), how do I revise the formula?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at bilinear interpolation

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation

which extends the idea you had to two dimensions.

Comment: Thank for answering!